# How to Insert 3D annotation to PDF document with iText?

Tags: c#, 3d, annotations, itext

How to Insert 3D annotation to existing multipage PDF document with **iText**?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? What doesn't work?

You can have a look at the list of iText's example, by [keyword](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php).

Depending on your needs, this [example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=299) might be what you are looking for.

Please note that these examples are written in Java, but the adaptation to C# should be straighforward.

Comment: I made by [this example](http://forum.planetpdf.com/wb/default.asp?action=9&read=58875&fid=103) because there were problems with the camera. Can be somehow to use PDF Stamper?